# Value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' has no member 'string' in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsmutabledictionary

I am new in swift and I am getting error in xcode 12.3. Before it was working fine

my code is like this

```
let dictOption = options[0] as! NSMutableDictionary
 btn2.setTitle(dictOption.string(forKey: "optionValue"), for: .normal)
```

but it is showing error

```
Value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' has no member 'string'
```

did anyone face the similar issue.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
dictOption.string(forKey: "optionValue")
```

with

```
dictOption.value(forKey: "optionValue")
```

Or more `Swifty`

```
guard let dic = options.first as? [String:Any] , 
      let value = dic["optionValue"] as? String else { return }
btn2.setTitle(value, for: .normal)
```